# Куда нужно загрузить код google analytics on_sent_ok?

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста как вставить атрибут для форм
Куда нужно вставить, пробовал написать в input submit, выводит ошибку. Пробовал вставить через onclick и без onclick все равно ошибка

on_sent_ok: "ga('send', 'event', 'zayavka', 'zakazat')

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Категория `zayavka` Экшин `zakazat`

```
<input type="submit" value="Отправить" name="form[Submit]" onClick="ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'zayavka', eventAction: 'zakazat'})">
```

Для контакт форм 7

```
on_sent_ok: "ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'zayavka', eventAction: 'zakazat'});"
```

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста для чего тогда нужен on_sent_ok: впереди ? Это для php ?

Comment: С on_sent_ok тоже должен работать, я в ответе написал как его можно будет использовать